# How to add input data into hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a input field where user enter desired input and that data is copied into a hidden input field but the problem occurs when the new data replace old data

This is where i copy all the data

```
$('#ap').val(JSON.stringify(data));
```

this is the input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="ApCount" id="ap" value="">
```

Now if i add data like 'hello' then it is added to hidden input value then it looks like

```
<input type="hidden" name="ApCount" id="ap" value="hello">
```

now if again i enter 'how are you' then it replaces old data with new..

I want to keep both data like

```
1 - [{"ratio":"1","size":"S","quantity":"83"},{"ratio":"2","size":"M","quantity":"166"}]

2 - [{"ratio":"3","size":"M","quantity":"93"},{"ratio":"2","size":"M","quantity":"136"}]
```

These above json data should be numbered stored properly in hidden value

Here is the running code

```
$('body').on('click', '.export-btn', function() {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];

  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });

  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function () {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};

    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function (header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();   
    });

    data.push(h);
  });

  // Output the result
  $('#ap').val(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: Can you share a running code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HTML Code

<input id="getVal" value="" />
<button id="addBtn">Add</button>

// Jquery Code

    var arrayData = [];
    $("#addBtn").on("click", function() {
        var currentData = $("#getVal").val();
        arrayData.push({
            "count": arrayData.length + 1,
            "data": currentData
        });
        console.log(arrayData);
    });
```

you will get the updated jason every time in arrayData in Json Format. Hope you got the desired output.

Comment: I'm getting data from editable table not input field

Comment: above you have mentioned an input field..you should have added the complete scenario.

Comment: I told i'm storing data into hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have some way of knowing when new data is added, and that your `data` is an array this could be achieved by first retrieving the value and then pushing new data on to the stack. For example:

```js
var data = [
  [{"ratio":"1","size":"S","quantity":"83"}, {"ratio":"2","size":"M","quantity":"166"}]
];
var $apField = $('#ap');
$apField.val(JSON.stringify(data));


// sometime later on, you have an additional bit of data
// let's say this is inside of an event handler that has 
// constructed this data for you:
var newData = [{"ratio":"3","size":"M","quantity":"93"},{"ratio":"2","size":"M","quantity":"136"}];

// Now add it to the data already in the element
var newDataSet = JSON.parse($apField.val()); // get the existing data
newDataSet.push(newData); // add the new set
$apField.val(JSON.stringify(newDataSet)); // update the field.

console.log(JSON.parse($apField.val()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="ApCount" id="ap" value="">
```